# How to read from input until newline is found using scanf()?

Tags: c, format, scanf

I was asked to do a work in C when I'm supposed to read from input until there's a space and then until the user presses enter.
If I do this:

```
scanf("%2000s %2000s", a, b);
```

It will follow the 1st rule but not the 2nd.
If I write:

```
I am smart
```

What I get is equivalent to:
a = "I";
b = "am";
But It should be:
a = "I";
b = "am smart";

I already tried:

```
scanf("%2000s %2000[^\n]\n", a, b);
```

and

```
scanf("%2000s %2000[^\0]\0", a, b);
```

In the 1st one, it waits for the user to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (to send EOF) and that's not what I want.
In the 2nd one, it won't compile. According to the compiler:

> warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format

Any good way to solve this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`scanf` (and cousins) have one slightly strange characteristic: white space in (most placed in) the format string matches an arbitrary amount of white space in the input. As it happens, at least in the default "C" locale, a new-line is classified as white space.

This means the trailing `'\n'` is trying to match not only *a* new-line, but any succeeding white-space as well. It won't be considered matched until you signal the end of the input, or else enter some non-white space character.

One way to deal with that is something like this:

```
scanf("%2000s %2000[^\n]%c", a, b, &c);

if (c=='\n')
    // we read the whole line
else
    // the rest of the line was more than 2000 characters long. `c` contains a 
    // character from the input, and there's potentially more after that as well.
```

Depending on the situation, you might also want to check the return value from `scanf`, which tells you the number of conversions that were successful. In this case, you'd be looking for `3` to indicate that all the conversions were successful.

Comment: That's more like it! Now I get it. I didn't know that part about the blank character from the spec. Thanks, that's what I really needed. Also, thnx for the %c tip, it'll be useful for other uses.

Comment: 'outside of a scanset' is not enough: %c and %n are also exceptions

Comment: shouldn't it be `scanf(..., &c)`?

Comment: @HaxAddict1337: Oops, quite right. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

```
scanf("%2000s %2000[^\n]", a, b);
```

Answer (score 5):

use getchar and a while that look  like this

```
while(x = getchar())
{   
    if(x == '\n'||x == '\0')
       do what you need when space or return is detected
    else
        mystring.append(x)
}
```

Sorry if I wrote a pseudo-code but I don't work with C language from a while.

Comment: Now I understood what you mean. Still... I think that is a bit like complicating what can be made more simply. Nevertheless, that works.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  char *a = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
  while (1) {
    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    if (a[i] == '\n') {
      break;
    }
    else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  a[i] = '\0';
  i = 0;
  printf("\n");
  while (a[i] != '\0') {
    printf("%c", a[i]);
    i++;
  }
  free(a);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why so complex solution? Why do so many operations that are not necessary?

Comment: Yes brunoais You made a legit point! In my code I am doing a character by character reading which justifies the question "until",There are good optimized ways too. but for someone who started coding . My solution will be a good example on how things work.

Comment: @Bharadwaj_Turlapati Including <conio.h> and using getch() is not really a nice thing. Maybe someone is not developing or learning on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I am too late, but you can try this approach as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i=0, j=0, arr[100];
    char temp;
    while(scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp)){
        i++;
        if(temp=='\n'){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[5],b[10];
    scanf("%2000s %2000[^\n]s",a,b);
    printf("a=%s b=%s",a,b);
}
```

Just write s in place of \n :)

Comment: Also the `s` does not make sense here. `%[^\n]` already asks for all characters but a new-line.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char line[2000] = {'\0'};
  char word[2000] = {'\0'};
  while (fgets(line, 2000, stdin) != NULL) {
    // line now contains the entire line

    sscanf(line, "%s", word);
    // word now contains the first word
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the initial issue. The input can have 4001 character or more. The value of `line` at the end of the block is wrong too. See the example

Answer (score -2):

//increase char array size if u want take more no. of characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[10],s1[10];
    scanf("\n");//imp for below statement to work
    scanf("%[^\n]%c",s);//to take input till the you click enter
    scanf("%s",s1);//to take input till a space
    printf("%s",s);
    printf("%s",s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example, you are ignoring the input until the new line, you are not making safety checks, `s` will always be `\n`. Please see the accepted answer for an example answer.