# C string using pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

So, I want to get 5 string inputs from the user using array of pointers to strings. However, I want those strings to have white spaces and hence, I am using the %[^\n]s which accepts the string till a line break occurs. But, this code doesn't work :/ Can someone please explain why??

P.S-> If you use %s in scanf, the code works. But I want white spaces compulsorily. So, please suggest something.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void main()
{
        char *f[5];
        int i;
        printf("\nEnter 5 strings:\n");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            f[i]=malloc(20);
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            scanf("%[^\n]s",f[i]);
        printf("The 5 strings are:\n");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("\n%s",f[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `scanf` use `fgets()`.

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But why doesn't scanf work?

Comment: Please use braces - one gets embarrassed when having your trousers around your ankles.

Comment: Related but not necessarily duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097776/391161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to 'consume' the '\n' character after you've read what you want. Use the following format directive:

```
"%[^\n]%*c"
```

Which will read everything up to the newline into the string you pass in, then will consume a single character (the newline) without assigning it to anything (that '*' is 'assignment suppression').

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks so much :). But can you please explain why this [^\n]%s was the wrong choice? Pleaseee

Comment: When you use scanf() to read the strings, your format string (%[^\n]) tells the function to read every character that is not '\n'. That leaves the '\n' character in the input buffer. 
If this helped please vote it up

Answer (score 2):

One major problem is the trailing `'s'` in your format. If you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the `"%["` format is terminated by the `']'` character. When you have that extra `'s'` in the format, `scanf` will wait until it matches a literal `'s'` in the input.

And to skip the ending newline, you can add a leading whitespace in the format and `scanf` will automatically read and skip all whitespace (including newline) that you don't want in the next iteration of the loop.

You also should limit the length of the input `scanf` reads, or you might have `scanf` read more than you have allocated. The limit should be 19 characters (which with the string terminator is 20, like you have allocated).

So the correct format should be `" %19[^\n]"`.

---

As a side-note, since you allocate all strings equally, why not simply have an array of arrays? Like

```
char f[5][20];
```

And if you still decide to go with the pointers, don't forget to `free` them when you're done. You don't really need it in such a simple case such as your program, but it's better to get the good habits early.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining :) And yes i realize that arrays are the better way to go but I took 20 just as an example.. Actually I'm gonna have variable length strings so i figured pointers were easier.. I'm making my first dictionary! yayyyyy ^_^