# Printing number of lines in a file without using fgets

Tags: c, file-io

So I am trying to print the number of lines in a file. The catch is that I cannot use fgets. Is there any other alternative to this which involves only fscanf? 
I tried running the following:

```
while (1) {
  ret = fscanf(fin, "%[^\n]", string);
  if (ret == EOF) break;
  line_count++;
}
```

But it does not work. It is giving me an infinite loop. Can anyone please tell me what the issue is ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from input until newline is found using scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097620/how-to-read-from-input-until-newline-is-found-using-scanf)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Could you point out the flaw in my program?

Comment: You are scanning for everything except newline. Which means the scan gets stuck on the newline. The linked answer tells you how to scan for a line including the newline. You just need to adapt that to count the lines and do it in a loop.

Comment: Why would you use anything but `fgetc`? `scanf` is not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
ret = fscanf(fin, "%[^\n]", string);
```

should be:

```
ret = fscanf(fin, " %[^\n]", string);
```

Notice the leading space, which will consume any leading 'white space'

I agree with the comments about newlines.  Therefore, suggest:

```
size_t lineCount = 0;
int ch;
while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF )
{
    if( '\n' == ch )
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will consume consecutive newlines which defeats the objective of counting them.

Comment: You should also save the last character read before `EOF` (e.g. `int ch, last;`)  as the last command in your `while` set `last = ch;`, then at the end check `if (last != '\n') lineCount++;` to handle the case where the file doesn't contain a POSIX line-ending on the final line. (**note:** `ch` and `last` should be type `int` to detect `EOF`)

Answer (score 0):

You must also be aware of a *corner-case* not covered by the other answers. For a file to be POSIX compliant, the final character must be a `'\n'` character, or the file may be empty to begin with. For example, a two line file that contains a POSIX end-of-file could be:

```
my dog has fleas\n
my cat has none\n
```

If you were counting lines in the file above by counting the number of `'\n'` characters, your number of lines for the file would be as expected -- `2`. However, there are many editors today, that do no create POSIX compliant files because they fail to write the final `'\n'` after the last line of text. So many editors would leave the file as:

```
my dog has fleas\n
my cat has none
```

It is a perfectly legal way to save the file, it is just a non-POSIX way of doing so. Now, what would your program output if you were simply counting the `'\n'` characters to determine the lines in the file? (`1` -- you would count one-too-few lines)

To address the issue of a non-POSIX eof to ensure your line count is correct either way, you need to check the last character before `EOF` and see if it was a `'\n'`, and if it wasn't you need to add `+1` to your line count.

You can do that fairly simply just by saving the current character at the end of you loop so that it is preserved for comparison after `EOF` is encountered. You can do something like the following:

```
/* count lines in file from open file-stream.
 * returns number of lines in file, including files
 * with non-POSIX end-of-file.
 */
size_t linecount (FILE *fp)
{
    int c, last = 0;                    /* current and last char read */
    size_t nlines = 0;                  /* line counter */
    
    rewind(fp);                         /* prevent UB if EOF already set on fp */
    
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {    /* loop reading each char */
        if (c == '\n')                  /* if '\n' increment line counter */
            nlines++;
        last = c;                       /* save current as last */
    }
    /* if not empty-file and not POSIX eof, add 1 to nlines */
    return last && last != '\n' ? nlines + 1 : nlines;
}
```

The loop can also be written as:

```
    do {
        last = c;
        if ((c = fgetc(fp)) == '\n')
            nlines++;
    } while (c != EOF);
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.