# Incorrect counting of number of lines

Tags: c, while-loop, counting

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int c, nl;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ( c == '\n') {
      nl++;
      printf("\n%d", nl);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input :
asdsndjkasndasjldk
asdsndjkasndasjldk
asdsndjkasndasjldk
asdsndjkasndasjldk
asdsndjkasndasjldk

Output :
4

The code counts the number of input lines, however, when I compile and run the code it displays a number less than the actual number of lines.

EOF being End Of File...

Comment: So add `1` to the number?

Comment: `nl` is never initialized.  Turn on compiler warnings (and possibly optimization) and your compiler will tell you about this.

Comment: @NateEldredge While turning on warnings is a very good idea, this actually don't yield a warning with gcc. clang does however.

Comment: @klutt: It does for me: https://godbolt.org/z/mgZz4P.  As usual with gcc, you need `-Wall -O` to get warnings about uninitialized variables.  Hence my remark about optimization.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, I see. Had no idea I needed `-O` for that. I only used `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @NateEldredge clang seems to be smarter here. It says that it is uninitialized, which it is. But gcc only says that it *may be* uninitialized. It fails to see that that indeed always is the case.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks I forgot to declare nl, I initialized by nl = 1; thanks

Comment: @klutt: Not if the input file is empty (i.e. if `getchar()` returns `EOF` on the initial run).  And `getchar()` is a black box to gcc; for all it knows, it could be a function that always returns `EOF`.  So "may" is not wrong, if we want to get picky.  Though you're right in general that gcc tends to hedge and say "may"; these warnings are usually generated based on heuristics rather than proof, because proving it is the halting problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah, you're right. Also, it seems like clang does not have a "may be " warning. I did a test with an if statement.

Comment: See also [Printing number of lines in a file without using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60032606/3422102)

Answer (score 2):

I realized that defining the number of lines actually was a bit trickier than I thought. But after some thinking, I would use this algorithm with pseudo code:

```
no_lines = 0
while (c=read_character()) != EOF
    no_lines++
    if c != '\n'
        consume_rest_of_line()
```

I thought of some cases and what size I "wanted" them to have. The cases are shown below.

0 lines: (obvious)

```
<EOF>
```

1 line: (obvious)

```
Hello<EOF>
```

1 line: (little tricker, feels like 1 line, but it also feels like \n should affect things)

```
Hello\n<EOF>
```

1 line: (just HAS to be different than an empty file)

```
\n<EOF>
```

2 lines: (just HAS to have one more than the above)

```
\n
\n<EOF>
```

2 lines: (ok, i think i have it now)

```
\n
Hello<EOF>
```

When I looked at this, I realized that the number of lines is almost the number of `\n` but not quite. The `\n` only says that it's time to see if there is a next line or not. Any character, including `\n` may start a line, but a `\n` always ends current line irregardless if it started it or not.

So I ended up with this code:

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    size_t no_lines = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        no_lines++;
        if(c != '\n')
            while(((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n');
    }
    printf("%zu\n", no_lines);
}
```

Another way to express it is: "Count the number of `\n`, and if the last read character is NOT `\n`, then add one."

Comment: `int prev = 0;` (may be cleaner) and `if(prev && prev != '\n')` - to ensure the count is `0` for an empty file? Test with `printf "" | ./yourexe` and see if it works.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I sort of like initializeing to `! <something>`  because it conveys more information about my intentions. I can pick ANY number EXCEPT `\n` and that's the information I want to send to the reader. And I cannot see what good it would do to check if `prev` is zero or not. Seems very unnecessary.

Comment: Your initialization works -- `!'\n'` is equivalent to `!(0xa)` -- which is `0`, I just scratched my head when I looked at it and the "anything not a `'\n'`" explanation. The need for `if(prev && prev != '\n')` is to ensure `no_lines` remains `0` for an empty-file. As it is currently, you report `1` line for an empty-file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Actually, it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop, so I'll delete it and look at it tomorrow

Comment: No worries, the answer is good -- you just need to tweak it a bit. See [Count Lines in C](https://paste.opensuse.org/70610255) for a quick example of what I'm talking about -- feel free to use all or part.

Answer (score 2):

There is a semantic problem here. In Unix world a line in a text file is **terminated** by a newline character. A file that does not end in a new-line character is not even considered a text file. Contrary to that, many Windows programs tend to consider the newline character as a *line separator*.

The program calculates the number of newlines in the input. If the input is a text file, then it tells the number of lines too. If it is produced by a broken Windows editor or if you terminated the input *before* the last newline then it goes wrong. It would work correctly for Unix text files however.

---

This is not unique to this program. The POSIX utility [`wc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wc.html) has a switch `-l` which is commonly said to count *lines*, but it too actually calculates newline characters in the input! Consider this example:

```
% printf "abc\nabc\nabc\n" | wc -l
3
% printf "abc\nabc\nabc" | wc -l  
2
```

Comment: Interesting. That would mean that an empty file is not a text file.

Comment: @klutt an empty file is a text file because each of the 0 lines is terminated by a newline character.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hmmm, I was to fast there. But are you sure? I mean, you could also say that each of the 0 lines is NOT terminated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  First, you never initialized `nl` and so its value is indeterminate.

Second, consider a text file with just one line:

```
hello
```

That file contains only one line and yet there is no newline character.  You need to account for that (perhaps by initializing `nl` to 1).

Comment: I would advocate adding 1 at the end if the last read character was not '\n'.

Comment: And you likewise need to make sure that both `hello<EOF>` and `hello\n<EOF>` contain one line.  (Depending on your definition of "line").

Comment: @MadPhysicist Your nickname suits your question very well :D

Comment: @MadPhysicist how do I exactly add 1 in the end?

Comment: @NateEldredge It actually amazed me now how tricky "number of lines" actually can be to define for a simple text file

Comment: You keep track of the previous character. Set the initial value to `\n`, and if it's not `\n` at the end, increment by one.